# Evaluating an expression (like 45/12) from a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to type a value in a textbox of either 45/12 or 3.75 which is a decimal inch conversion. Obviously the decimal value works. The code takes a different textbox value (a) and this value (b) subtracts b from a and multiplies the result by a shrink factor to populate in another textbox. Some know the decimal conversion some do not and resort to the 45/12 method. Value (a) is entered strictly by a decimal conversion 8'-1" would be 8.0833. Any help on this is appreciated. Value (b) however is used for more calculations further in the code which I can post if needed. This is part of the code, the value for b goes on and on to an expression of >4. Also this is my first ever VB design so it may not be the most efficient code. thanks

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1



Dim a, b, c, d, r, w, h, x, y, z As Single
Dim s, t, u, v, f, g, j, k, l, m, n, o As Single

Private Sub radiobutton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If (RadioButton1.Checked) = False Then
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub radiobutton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    If (RadioButton3.Checked) = False Then
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Timer1.Interval = 1000 Then
        Label9.Text = DateTime.Now
    End If
End Sub


' Calculate Button Does This
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Error Boxes

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Input 'Wall Height' And/Or 'Depth'")
        With TextBox1
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Input 'Wall Height' And/Or 'Depth'")
        With TextBox2
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (RadioButton1.Checked Or RadioButton3.Checked) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please Select 'N/A' or 'Yes")
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text < TextBox2.Text Then
        MsgBox("Re-check Depth and Wall Height")
        With TextBox1
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Values For Depth And Wall Height

    a = Val(TextBox1.Text) 'Depth
    b = Val(TextBox2.Text) 'Actual Wall Height



    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Hopper Drop Shrink Calculation

    If (RadioButton3.Checked) AndAlso ((a - b) <= 1) Then
        r = Math.Round(((a - b) - 0.0833), 4)
    ElseIf (RadioButton1.Checked) Then
        r = Math.Round(((a - b) * 0.944), 4) ' Depth minus wall height .944 shrink factor
    ElseIf (RadioButton3.Checked) Then
        r = Math.Round(((a - b) * 0.89), 4) ' Depth minus wall height .89 shrink factor
    End If

    If r <= 0.01 Then
        TextBox3.Text = "N/A"
    Else : TextBox3.Text = r
    End If
    ' Value For Hopper Drop after shrink





    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Depth Minus Wall Height Ranges For Finish Wall Height

    w = (b >= 0.0833 And b <= 3.25) ' Wall height between 12" and 39"
    If w Then
        h = Math.Round(((b - 0.0833) * 12), 2) ' Subtract 1" from wall height
    End If

    If w Then
        t = 0
    End If

    If w Then
        d = 0
    End If


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    z = (b >= 3.26 And b <= 3.3332) ' Wall height between 39 1/4" and 39 3/4"
    If z Then
        h = 38 ' Wall height will be 38"
    End If

    If z Then
        t = 0
    End If

    If z Then
        d = 0
    End If

TextBox4.Text = Int(h) & " " & DecToFraction(h - Int(h)) & "''" 'Finish Wall Height
    TextBox6.Text = Int(t) & " " & DecToFraction(t - Int(t)) & "''" ' Strip Size
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        TextBox5.Text = "N/A"
    ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        TextBox5.Text = Int(t) & " " & DecToFraction(t - Int(t)) & "''" ' Wrap Size
    End If

    TextBox7.Text = Int(d) & " " & DecToFraction(d - Int(d)) & "''" ' Cut wall to (production wall height)
```

Comment: Can you provide us a minimally-reproducible code?

Comment: code added to the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) to treat the textbox input as a mathematical expression.  This would handle `45/12` and `3.75` perfectly, as either will evaluate to a single number when executed through the expression engine.

Comment: so if (a) = 8.0833 and (b) equals 40/12 or 3.3333, I'm not sure what expression to use for NCalc

Comment: I cannot get this to produce the results I am looking for. `code`Dim exp As New Expression(TextBox1.Text)

        exp.Evaluate()
        TextBox12.Text = exp.ToString()  `code` and I get NCalc.Expression in textbox.12

Comment: @EricDeVault CHeck docs - I think you need: `TextBox12.Text = exp.Evaluate().ToString();`

Comment: `Dim exp As New Expression(TextBox1.Text)

        TextBox12.Text = Math.Round((exp.Evaluate()), 4)`   @reedcopsey this worked for me, pretty much the same thing you just posted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a `Fraction` struct like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fraction X=Fraction.Parse("45/12");
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0} = {1} = {2}", X, X.GetReduced(),X.Value);
        // X = 45/12 = 15/4 = 3.75
        bool ok=X.Equals(3.75);
        // true
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A Class to represent fraction from decimals using GCD and LCM.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Code taken from http://www.vcskicks.com/code-snippet/fraction.php</remarks>
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public struct Fraction : IEquatable<Fraction>, IEquatable<double>, ICloneable
{
    public static string DefaultFormat="G";
    public readonly long numerator;
    public readonly long denominator;
    public static Fraction Zero=new Fraction(0, 1);

    public Fraction(long numerator, long denominator)
    {
        this.numerator=numerator;
        this.denominator=denominator;

        //If denominator negative...
        if(this.denominator<0)
        {
            //...move the negative up to the numerator
            this.numerator=-this.numerator;
            this.denominator=-this.denominator;
        }
    }

    public Fraction(Fraction fraction)
    {
        this.numerator=fraction.numerator;
        this.denominator=fraction.denominator;
    }

    public static Fraction Parse(string value)
    {
        long num=1;
        long den=1;
        string[] parts=value.Split('/');
        bool is_den=false;
        for(int i=0; i<parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if(is_den)
            {
                den*=long.Parse(parts[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                num*=long.Parse(parts[i]);
            }
            is_den=!is_den;
        }
        return new Fraction(num, den);
    }
    public static implicit operator Fraction(double value)
    {
        return Fraction.FromValue(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator double(Fraction rhs)
    {
        return rhs.Value;
    }

    public long Numerator { get { return numerator; } }
    public long Denominator { get { return denominator; } }
    public double Value { get { return (double)numerator/denominator; } }

    public static Fraction operator+(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs) { return lhs.Add(rhs); }
    public static Fraction operator-(Fraction rhs) { return rhs.Negate(); }
    public static Fraction operator-(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs) { return lhs.Subtract(rhs); }
    public static Fraction operator*(double lhs, Fraction rhs) { return rhs.Scale(lhs); }
    public static Fraction operator*(Fraction lhs, double rhs) { return lhs.Scale(rhs); }
    public static Fraction operator/(Fraction lhs, double rhs) { return lhs.Scale(1/rhs); }
    public static Fraction operator/(double lhs, Fraction rhs) { return rhs.Reciprocal(lhs); }
    public static Fraction operator*(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs) { return lhs.Multiply(rhs); }
    public static Fraction operator/(Fraction lhs, Fraction rhs) { return lhs.Divide(rhs); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the greatest common divisor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static long getGCD(long a, long b)
    {
        //Drop negative signs
        a=Math.Abs(a);
        b=Math.Abs(b);

        //Return the greatest common denominator between two integers
        while(a!=0&&b!=0)
        {
            if(a>b)
                a%=b;
            else
                b%=a;
        }

        if(a==0)
            return b;
        else
            return a;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the least common measure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static long getLCM(long a, long b)
    {
        //Return the Least Common Denominator between two integers
        return (a*b)/getGCD(a, b);
    }

    public Fraction ToDenominator(long targetDenominator)
    {
        //Multiply the fraction by a factor to make the denominator
        //match the target denominator
        //Fraction modifiedFraction=this;
        long n=this.numerator;
        long d=this.denominator;

        //Cannot reduce to smaller denominators
        if(targetDenominator<this.denominator)
            return this;

        //The target denominator must be a factor of the current denominator
        if(targetDenominator%this.denominator!=0)
            return this;

        if(d!=targetDenominator)
        {
            long factor=targetDenominator/d;
            n*=factor;
            d=targetDenominator;
            //modifiedFraction.denominator=targetDenominator;
            //modifiedFraction.numerator*=factor;
        }

        return new Fraction(n, d);
    }

    public Fraction GetReduced()
    {
        //Reduce the fraction to lowest terms
        //Fraction modifiedFraction=this;
        long n=this.numerator;
        long d=this.denominator;

        //While the numerator and denominator share a greatest common denominator,
        //keep dividing both by it
        long gcd=0;
        while(Math.Abs(gcd=getGCD(n, d))!=1)
        {
            n/=gcd;
            d/=gcd;
        }

        //Make sure only a single negative sign is on the numerator
        n=n*Math.Sign(d);
        d=Math.Abs(d);

        return new Fraction(n, d);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a continious fraction scheme to iteratively aproximate a number with a fraction. 
    /// The accuracy is taken from <see cref="GRE.Mathematics.Dbl.Calculator.ZeroTolerance"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>See <see cref="FromValue(double,double)"/> to understand how it works</remarks>
    /// <param name="number">The number to approximate</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Fraction FromValue(double number)
    {
        return FromValue(number, 15);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a continious fraction scheme to iteratively aproximate a number with a fraction
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>See <see cref="FromValue(double,double)"/> to understand how it works</remarks>
    /// <param name="number">The number to approximate</param>
    /// <param name="digits">The number if digits to use in the aproximation</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Fraction FromValue(double number, int digits)
    {
        double accuracy=Math.Pow(10.0, -digits);
        return FromValue(number, accuracy);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a continious fraction scheme to iteratively aproximate a number with a fraction
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// See documentation for <see cref="FromContiniousFractionCoefficients(long[])"/> to understand how this works.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="number">The number to aproximate</param>
    /// <param name="accuracy">The accuracy to use |fraction-value|<![CDATA[<]]>accuracy </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Fraction FromValue(double number, double accuracy)
    {
        int sign=Math.Sign(number);
        number=Math.Abs(number);
        int passes=0;
        List<long> coef=new List<long>();
        Fraction x;
        double r=number;  // remainder (example 8.22)
        do
        {
            long c=(int)r;    // integer of remainder (r=8.22 -> c=8)
            r=1/(r-c);    // new remainder from r -> 1/(0.22)=4.54
            coef.Add(c);        // adds c to the list
            x=FromContiniousFractionCoefficients(coef.ToArray());  // reconstruct the fraction from all the n's
            passes++;           // increment counter and repeat
        } while(!x.Equals(number, accuracy)&&passes<10);
        if(sign<0)
        {
            x=x.Negate();
        }
        return x;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Use recursion to take the integer coefficients of a continious fraction and simplify it to a regular fraction
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>The parameters in array <c>c</c> define the following value:<![CDATA[
    ///                  1
    ///  c[0] + -------------------- -> recursion on e[i] = c[i] + 1/e[i+1] , e[i]=r[i]/r[i+1]
    ///                    1
    ///       c[1] + ---------------         seed is 1/e[N]=0 (r[N]=1, r[N+1]=0)
    ///                       1              final result is x = r[0]/r[1]
    ///             c[2] + ---------      
    ///                     c[3]+...
    /// ]]></example>
    /// <remarks>Here are some references
    /// * http://www.friesian.com/golden.htm
    /// * http://archives.math.utk.edu/articles/atuyl/confrac/intro.html
    /// * http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/numberTheory/continuedFractions.htm
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="coef">The integer coefficients for the fraction (see example)</param>
    /// <returns>A Fraction object</returns>
    public static Fraction FromContiniousFractionCoefficients(params long[] coef)
    {
        int N=coef.Length;
        if(N>0)
        {
            long[] r=new long[N+2];
            r[N+1]=0;
            r[N+0]=1;
            for(int i=N-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                r[i]=coef[i]*r[i+1]+r[i+2];
            }
            return new Fraction(r[0], r[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            return Fraction.Zero;
        }
    }

    public Fraction Flip()
    {
        //Flip the numerator and the denominator
        return new Fraction(this.denominator, this.numerator);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Fraction)
        {
            return Equals((Fraction)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool Equals(Fraction other, double tolerance)
    {
        return Math.Abs(Value-other.Value)<=tolerance;
    }
    public bool Equals(Fraction other)
    {
        var A=GetReduced();
        var B=other.GetReduced();
        return A.numerator==B.numerator&&A.denominator==B.denominator;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return 17*23*Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public Fraction Clone() { return new Fraction(this); }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }


    public Fraction Scale(double factor)
    {
        Fraction other=new Fraction(factor);
        return Multiply(other);
    }

    public Fraction Divide(double factor)
    {
        Fraction other=new Fraction(factor);
        return Divide(other);
    }

    public Fraction Reciprocal(double numerator)
    {
        Fraction other=new Fraction(numerator);
        return other.Divide(this);
    }

    public Fraction Multiply(Fraction other)
    {
        return new Fraction(numerator*other.numerator, denominator*other.denominator).GetReduced();
    }

    public Fraction Divide(Fraction other)
    {
        return new Fraction(numerator*other.denominator, denominator*other.numerator).GetReduced();
    }

    public Fraction Add(Fraction other)
    {
        return new Fraction(other.denominator*numerator+other.numerator*denominator, denominator*other.denominator).GetReduced();
    }

    public Fraction Subtract(Fraction other)
    {
        return new Fraction(other.denominator*numerator-other.numerator*denominator, denominator*other.denominator).GetReduced();
    }

    public Fraction Negate()
    {
        return new Fraction(-numerator, denominator);
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(DefaultFormat);
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, null);
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if(numerator==0)
        {
            string fmt="{0:#}".Replace("#", format);
            return string.Format(formatProvider, fmt, numerator);
        }
        else
        {
            string fmt="{0:#}/{1:#}".Replace("#", format);
            return string.Format(formatProvider, fmt, numerator, denominator);
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(double other)
    {
        return Value.Equals(other);
    }
    public bool Equals(double other, double tolerance)
    {
        return Math.Abs(Value-other)<=tolerance;
    }


}
```